# Using local Python modules from python -c '...'

Tags: python, shell

I'm having trouble getting the Python 3.5 CLI to run commands with the `-c` switch.

If I try `python3 -c "print(5 + 9)"` in the shell, the output is `14` as expected.

However, I have a file in the current working directory called `gcd.py` that looks like this:

```
def gcd(m, n):
    return m if n == 0 else gcd(n, m % n)
```

If I run `python3 -m gcd -c "print(gcd(48, 18))"` the shell just creates a new command prompt without outputting anything.

If I change the file to:

```
print('test')

def gcd(m, n):
    return m if n == 0 else gcd(n, m % n)
```

then the shell will output `test`, so the file is being loaded. Does anybody know what I'm doing wrong? Thanks.

Comment: There's nothing CLI-specific about this mode -- it's often used to embed Python code in bash scripts, for instance, with no expectation that those scripts be used interactively.

Answer (score 4):

You can't use `-m` and `-c` together; either one or the other controls execution. Specifying them both makes Python ignore them.

Use an `import` statement in `-c` instead:

```
python3 -c "from gcd import gcd; print(gcd(48, 18))"
```

Note that `-m` treats the module as a script, it is not a 'import this module first' switch for `-c`.